# Can this code be concatenated?

Tags: conditional-tags

I realise this is perhaps more of a php question, but it relates to WP use.

Can the example below, be modified (and if so, how?) to fully concatenate the 2 echos rather than having them separate?

```
if... {
echo '<p>', get_template_part( 'templates/xxx' );
echo '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more a PHP question

you can try these folowing forms :

```
if (...) {
    echo '<p>';
    get_template_part('templates/xxx');
    echo '</p>';
}
```

or

```
if (...) {
    ?>
        <p>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/xxx'); ?>
        </p>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've learned... didn't know that the 'get_template_part' would process rather than be echoed.

Comment: Quick update... when using a period to concatenate, the template loads in an incorrect order.

Comment: I've edited the answer. The first example was incorrect. You can't concatenate `get_template_part()` like that.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie  Thanks. :-) To me, it's all learning - so I now know more than before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do it like this if you need to return the data instead of echo it. Useful for in functions and AJAX callbacks and such.

```
// Start HTML
ob_start();
?>

    <p><?php get_template_part( 'templates/xxx' ); ?></p>

<?php   

$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $html;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's quickly getting beyond my relatively small knowledge, so I'll probably stick with my original 'double echo' - because I understand that and hence am still likely to if ever re-looking at it in the future and wondering 'what did I do there?'.